# Removing specific strings

Tags: python

I have the following block of code. Can I have a line that removes specific strings before writing?

```
while str(line).find("ii") < 0:
    if str(line)[0].isdigit():
        if str(line).find("No Action Taken") < 0 and str(line).find("Existing IV Retest") < 0:
            #<----LINE HERE TO REMOVE ANYTHING I SPECIFY------> example anything in brackets [),(,&,&,#,@]
            f.write(str(line).strip())
            f.write(',')
```

Comment: What is `line` if not a string?

Comment: @nightcracker the code in the question may be incorrect since the indentation was lost and then re-added by someone who edited the question. The last line may or may not be at the correct indentation level.

Comment: @Seth Unindented one-line code in a language without significant whitespace would still be completely unreadable. And the indentation isn't lost when you don't use proper markdown for code samples - it just isn't displayed.

Comment: Please don't mine the improper indentation. It's the bottom half of my code. Code is working.

Comment: @Jeff: that's not true: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/824fa891-a821-4342-914f-ef64b888c28c/view-source

Comment: @sepp2k it was completely lost and added by a third party here (Tim). Also that's not true, in a language without significant white space you can reliably re-add the white space and the code will still work even without it. But in Python, you have to basically almost rewrite the program and understand all of it and where it should go.

Comment: Guys, take your language wars somewhere else! Stay on topic please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit cryptic, but I think you're looking for regular expressions.

If you want to remove anything within brackets from a string:

```
import re
line = "hello [delete this] there!"
line = re.sub(
              r"""(?x)  # Verbose regex:
              \[        # Match a [
              [^][]*    # Match zero or more (*) characters except (^) ] or [
              \]        # Match a ]""", 
              "", line)
```

Result:

```
line == 'hello  there!'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm very new to python and regex completely scare the crap of out me. Yes this is exactly what I need. But don't understand the code. I have read the manual at http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html but still don't get it.

Comment: @fpena06: I've changed the regex into a commented one; hope that helps. If you want to learn how to construct regexes, I suggest http://www.regular-expressions.info as a starting point. For the above regex, check out http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly:

The normal way:

```
for i in [')','(','&','&','#','@']:
    line = line.replace(i,'')
```

The one line way:

```
line = reduce(lambda a,b: a.replace(b,''), [')','(','&','&','#','@'], line)
```

Example:

```
>>> line = "blah!@#*@!)*%^(*%^)@*(#$)@#*$)@#*@#)@$*)@!*#)@#@!)#*%$)$#%$%blah"
>>> line = reduce(lambda a,b: a.replace(b,''), [')','(','&','&','#','@'], line)
>>> print line
blah!*!*%^*%^*$*$*$*!*!*%$$%$%blah
```

Comment: That's how he wrote it. I was going for as simple a conversion as possible, for pedagogical purposes.

Comment: Yes. Right, I just saw he did the same. I thought you wrote it by mistake, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use `line = line.replace('#', '')` to remove '#' from the string. You could repeat that statement for all the characters you want to remove (not specifically characters BTW).

But, much better would be to use regular expressions (for more complex patterns too), available through the `re` package in Python.

Something like: `line = re.sub(re_pattern, "", line)`